# combining multiple javascript var into one function

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui

I know absolutely nothing about js but I stumbled on this and was wondering if someone could help me combine these two into one. I will probably end up having about 30 of them. is it possible for all 30 vars to be combined? each customPush will push a new html.

Thank you.

```
var customPush1 = function (event) {
myNavigator.pushPage('pageNav2.html', { data: { cardTitle: 
event.target.textContent } })
};
var customPush2 = function (event) {
myNavigator.pushPage('pageNav3.html', { data: { cardTitle: event.target.textContent } })
};
```

Comment: so, you'll have `customPush1` ... `customPush30` ?

Comment: In what way do you mean combine,..  do you still want  `customPush1` & `customPush2` functions,. but make it so the code is shared?..

Comment: yes. the plan is to have 30 buttons loading a separate html each .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yes. the plan is to have 30 buttons loading a separate html each

In this case, I'd do it a different way, rather than creating lots of functions, I would add some data-attributes to the buttons, and use delegated events.

But if you want to make it so that you can share code between functions.  You can create a function that returns a function, and use closures to pass parameters.  Below is an example.

```js
function makePush(url) {
  return function (event) {
    myNavigator.pushPage(url, { data: { cardTitle: 
      event.target.textContent } })
  }
}

var 
  customPush1 = makePush('pageNav2.html'),
  customPush2 = makePush('pageNav3.html');
```

And here is an example of using delegated events on the buttons.  It's uses jQuery as I find it quick and easy, but the same can be done without jQuery.

```js
$('body').on('click', '[data-custom-push]', function () {
  var page = $(this).attr('data-custom-push');
  alert('Page = ' + page);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-custom-push="pageNav1.html">Button 1</button> <br>
<button data-custom-push="pageNav2.html">Button 2</button> <br>
<button data-custom-push="pageNav3.html">Button 3</button> <br>
<button data-custom-push="pageNav4.html">Button 4</button> <br>
<button data-custom-push="pageNav5.html">Button 5</button> <br>
<button data-custom-push="xyz.html">Button 6</button> <br>
<button data-custom-push="abc.html">Button 7</button> <br>
```